# VMWare - Connecting two hosts (not physically connected) via a vSwitch

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, vswitch

I have an esxi 5.5 host in Chicago and Dallas. Both servers are controlled by my vcenter server. I have a MySQL server in chicago that is accessed through an internal only vswitch from the servers on that host. I now need to access it from the Dallas host as well. Is there any way to connect the private networks of the two hosts via vSwitches? (i'm not looking to do any GRE tunnels, TE tunnels, or VPNs. If something internal to vmware isn't possible, then that's all i need to know!) thanks!

Comment: I don't see how this would be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either have an internal vSwitch that is internal and can interconnect them with GRE-tunnels (which you don't want) or make the vSwitch external. There is no other way to interconnect vSwitches accross different networks.